# JavaFX import 3D models

Tags: 3d, javafx

I want to import some 3d models to my javaFX application.

In javaFX I can create rectangles, traingles, circles, pentagons.
Those figures can be filled with color or filled with image.
They are called nodes. Nodes can be added to group and be visible ( nodes also can be rotated, scaled and translated ).

I want to import 3d model and it to be as a node, so I could add model to a group and rotate, scale and translate.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/shape3d.htm#CBHIEGDD

Comment: This link writes hows to build geometric 3D figures for scene.

Comment: But I have .stl file, and I want add it to scene. How to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [these importers](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html). They also support STL for importing.